# SQL insert varchar into image

Tags: sql

I have two tables; the first one contains these columns:

```
image_path varchar
id uniqueidentifier
```

and the second has these columns:

```
image image
id unique identifier
```

How can I insert the `image_path` into `image` when I use cast or convert to `varbinary` then to image it Mack all columns the same value and when I use bulk I must insert the path manually do you have query to this problem

Comment: An image is an image, and a path is a path...

Comment: You cannot. In a `image` column cannot store a `varchar`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load the image and save it to the database, then this might work:

```
INSERT INTO table2(image)
SELECT rs.* FROM table1
JOIN OPENROWSET(BULK table1.image_path, SINGLE_BLOB) AS rs
```

Comment: its get me 3 error firs one in rs.* (the colum prefix rs dos not math with table name) the second in table1.image_path (incorrect syntax near table1 expecting string or text_lex ) the third in single_blob (invalid object name )